# widely applicable question badge & tab

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, tabs

***Edit***

*There are millions of questions on Stack Overflow. I think a widely applicable to a large audience or reproducible question should organize some way, and that why I request this feature (for badge & tab option). So that  a user can find & study the proper way (maybe I am wrong or opinion based ).. although there is vote up & viewed way. I think those ways do not fill up the actual purpose, and that is why I think something is required for this purpose like my feature request* **below**...

***End Edit***

When I go to start a bounty I see there is an option   ***The question is widely applicable to a large audience***.

From this, I thought about if any question is actually  widely applicable to a large audience. I think Stack Overflow can offer a badge for this type of question.

Also I am thinking about how can I find those type of  posts to study. also consider a tab option for this.

***How will the award be given?***

It will be decided by high rep (like 10k rep) hold user or moderator or anyhow Stack Overflow will decide by voting something like which user can vote for close vote or reopen vote.

Comment: The conditions for this are too open for this to happen. Questions like this typically receive upvotes if they are asked well: what's wrong with just that?

Comment: @Toby Mak all widely applicable question not get more vote ..i think if questions get more vote it does not mean widely applicable

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the reputation increase be enough? For instance, questions tagged as Java on SO get more attention because more users know Java than say, Kotlin. It wouldn't be fair for people posting questions about Java to get a badge just for being popular.

Comment: @Toby Mak I write about this that study purpose also propose a tab and there is thousand of question.. why you take it negatively ?

Comment: @Toby Mak I think this fun will encourage users to share knowledge and will be aware of asking question. and if SO can create tab for those type of questions . it will more  encourage to share knowledge & help to study.   don't know why are you talking rep ? there is a lot of way to earn it... what can i do by rep

Comment: Users are already rewarded by gaining reputation, so why would they need a badge on top of that?

Comment: @Toby Mak i said about it study purpose .. i try to learn widely applicable question not more vote up question . also user easily can study through tab and will get more benefit .. plz think  positively

Comment: @noor Generally, more upvoted questions _are_ widely applicable, because people upvote questions and answers that help them.  Same for more viewed questions, though less directly - they likely viewed it due to having the same issue.  If you want to study such questions, you can sort questions by score.

Comment: @Ryan M  I think partially you right .. but all widely applicable question not get more vote or viewed..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @Sonic the Curiouser Hedgehog  no

Answer (score 10):

We already have badges for widely applicable questions:

For questions viewed by many people, we have [Popular Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) (Question with 1,000 views), [Notable Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/notable-question) (Question with 2,500 views), and [Famous Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) (Question with 10,000 views).

Questions that are widely applicable to a large audience are also frequently highly voted, resulting in large reputation gains, as well as the [Nice Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) (Question score of 10 or more), [Good Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question) (Question score of 25 or more), and [Great Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/great-question) (Question score of 100 or more) badges.

With these three rewards for widely applicable questions, we don't need a fourth option.

Comment: I know what you wrote...that was not my feature request...do you think most viewed question are largely applicable ? I think no... i try to delete my question ... would you delete your ans ?

Comment: @noor with respect, I spent time writing this answer in response to your question, and others spent their time reading and voting on it.  Why should I remove it and let that time go to waste?

Comment: that is why i request to you ... as yourwish ..never mind ..